# " 488 Incompatible SDP " when trying to send invite request to FreeSwitch with jssip library

Tags: javascript, webrtc, sip, freeswitch, jssip

Invite request always fails with **488** code. I tried to change the priority of codecs, but nothing helps. I think FreeSwitch is expecting another sdp parameters from what I'm sending to. But I can't figure it out. Here is the log from jssip debugger, I just changed ip adresses to **x.x.x.x**.

```
v=0
o=- 7053635878008465242 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS LLoltKhXZLs6dDQo6D1Qg6Nhx2VbpUlEkacK
m=audio 58498 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 x.x.x.x
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:315564084 1 udp 2122260223 x.x.x.x 58498 typ host generation 0 network-id 1
a=candidate:1548541124 1 tcp 1518280447 x.x.x.x 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1
a=ice-ufrag:kqqf
a=ice-pwd:Bo7IzjUSw39WMok8l9Uc4BI/
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 D6:9A:AD:65:35:2F:D3:64:69:68:2B:98:BC:E0:8C:DB:FE:4B:78:32:BA:B4:F2:13:B9:37:1C:ED:0C:71:C7:72
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
a=extmap:6 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
a=sendrecv
a=msid:LLoltKhXZLs6dDQo6D1Qg6Nhx2VbpUlEkacK 833bef1c-9465-43ac-a6bb-b0c6a2e60220
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:3691025739 cname:7gjkeRo/Y8ZrdWan
a=ssrc:3691025739 msid:LLoltKhXZLs6dDQo6D1Qg6Nhx2VbpUlEkacK 833bef1c-9465-43ac-a6bb-b0c6a2e60220
a=ssrc:3691025739 mslabel:LLoltKhXZLs6dDQo6D1Qg6Nhx2VbpUlEkacK
a=ssrc:3691025739 label:833bef1c-9465-43ac-a6bb-b0c6a2e60220
```

upd. here is updated freeswitch logs

```
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 v=0
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 o=- 4967169917273925077 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 s=-
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 t=0 0
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=group:BUNDLE 0
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=msid-semantic: WMS Kw4JikjGTLr1YL33aFwdEgZdJF4fdtm1aRij
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 m=audio 55901 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 c=IN IP4 x.x.x.x
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=rtcp:55902 IN IP4 x.x.x.x
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=candidate:315564084 1 udp 2122260223 x.x.x.x 55901 typ host generation 0 network-id 1
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=candidate:315564084 2 udp 2122260222 x.x.x.x 55902 typ host generation 0 network-id 1
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=candidate:1548541124 1 tcp 1518280447 x.x.x.x 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=candidate:1548541124 2 tcp 1518280446 x.x.x.x 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=ice-ufrag:GdU+
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=ice-pwd:uOgkz/P3qQL4S0g+Mnsf6Z9g
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=ice-options:trickle
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=fingerprint:sha-256 11:38:62:05:CB:01:40:B3:F1:50:F5:19:CF:18:12:78:25:6D:5F:9D:B9:3C:B6:F6:6C:90:5F:78:5F:12:24:1E
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=setup:actpass
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=mid:0
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=extmap:6 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=msid:Kw4JikjGTLr1YL33aFwdEgZdJF4fdtm1aRij c17fec62-2bff-40f1-9236-60945fcca1f8
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=rtcp-mux
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=ssrc:210706363 cname:5DUGvruPEE/VHCAx
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=ssrc:210706363 msid:Kw4JikjGTLr1YL33aFwdEgZdJF4fdtm1aRij c17fec62-2bff-40f1-9236-60945fcca1f8
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=ssrc:210706363 mslabel:Kw4JikjGTLr1YL33aFwdEgZdJF4fdtm1aRij
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 a=ssrc:210706363 label:c17fec62-2bff-40f1-9236-60945fcca1f8
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [opus:111:48000:20:0:1]/[PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [opus:111:48000:20:0:1]/[PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [opus:111:48000:20:0:1]/[opus:116:48000:20:0:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4504 Audio Codec Compare [opus:116:48000:20:0:1] ++++ is saved as a match
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [opus:111:48000:20:0:1]/[G7221:115:32000:20:48000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [opus:111:48000:20:0:1]/[G7221:107:16000:20:32000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [opus:111:48000:20:0:1]/[G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [ISAC:103:16000:30:32000:1]/[PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [ISAC:103:16000:30:32000:1]/[PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [ISAC:103:16000:30:32000:1]/[opus:116:48000:20:0:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [ISAC:103:16000:30:32000:1]/[G7221:115:32000:20:48000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [ISAC:103:16000:30:32000:1]/[G7221:107:16000:20:32000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [ISAC:103:16000:30:32000:1]/[G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [ISAC:104:32000:30:32000:1]/[PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [ISAC:104:32000:30:32000:1]/[PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [ISAC:104:32000:30:32000:1]/[opus:116:48000:20:0:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [ISAC:104:32000:30:32000:1]/[G7221:115:32000:20:48000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [ISAC:104:32000:30:32000:1]/[G7221:107:16000:20:32000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [ISAC:104:32000:30:32000:1]/[G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]/[opus:116:48000:20:0:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]/[G7221:115:32000:20:48000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]/[G7221:107:16000:20:32000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]/[G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4504 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1] ++++ is saved as a match
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4504 Audio Codec Compare [PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1] ++++ is saved as a match
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]/[opus:116:48000:20:0:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]/[G7221:115:32000:20:48000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]/[G7221:107:16000:20:32000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]/[G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4504 Audio Codec Compare [PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1] ++++ is saved as a match
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]/[opus:116:48000:20:0:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]/[G7221:115:32000:20:48000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]/[G7221:107:16000:20:32000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]/[G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [CN:105:16000:20:0:1]/[PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [CN:105:16000:20:0:1]/[PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [CN:105:16000:20:0:1]/[opus:116:48000:20:0:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [CN:105:16000:20:0:1]/[G7221:115:32000:20:48000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [CN:105:16000:20:0:1]/[G7221:107:16000:20:32000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [CN:105:16000:20:0:1]/[G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [CN:13:8000:20:0:1]/[PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [CN:13:8000:20:0:1]/[PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [CN:13:8000:20:0:1]/[opus:116:48000:20:0:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [CN:13:8000:20:0:1]/[G7221:115:32000:20:48000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [CN:13:8000:20:0:1]/[G7221:107:16000:20:32000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4449 Audio Codec Compare [CN:13:8000:20:0:1]/[G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4365 Set telephone-event payload to 110@48000
2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] mod_opus.c:603 Opus encoder: set bitrate to local settings [72000bps]
2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] mod_opus.c:603 Opus encoder: set bitrate to local settings [72000bps]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:3061 Set Codec sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89 opus/48000 20 ms 960 samples 0 bits 1 channels
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_codec.c:111 sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89 Original read codec set to opus:116
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:3481 Save audio Candidate cid: 1 proto: udp type: host addr: x.x.x.x:55901
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:3481 Save audio Candidate cid: 2 proto: udp type: host addr: x.x.x.x:55902
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:3523 Searching for rtp candidate.
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:3523 Searching for rtcp candidate.
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:3567 sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89 no suitable candidates found.
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4708 Set telephone-event payload to 110@48000
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4767 sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89 Set 2833 dtmf send payload to 110 recv payload to 110
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [NOTICE] sofia.c:7565 Hangup sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89 [CS_NEW] [INCOMPATIBLE_DESTINATION]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:603 (sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89) State NEW
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:584 (sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89) Running State Change CS_HANGUP (Cur 1 Tot 1548)
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:850 (sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89) Callstate Change DOWN -> HANGUP
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:852 (sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89) State HANGUP
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:438 Channel sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89 hanging up, cause: INCOMPATIBLE_DESTINATION
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:577 Responding to INVITE with: 488
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:60 sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89 Standard HANGUP, cause: INCOMPATIBLE_DESTINATION
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:852 (sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89) State HANGUP going to sleep
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:619 (sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89) State Change CS_HANGUP -> CS_REPORTING
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:584 (sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89) Running State Change CS_REPORTING (Cur 1 Tot 1548)
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.631217 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:938 (sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89) State REPORTING
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.651159 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:174 sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89 Standard REPORTING, cause: INCOMPATIBLE_DESTINATION
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.651159 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:938 (sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89) State REPORTING going to sleep
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.651159 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:610 (sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89) State Change CS_REPORTING -> CS_DESTROY
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.651159 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1665 Session 1548 (sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89) Locked, Waiting on external entities
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.651159 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1683 Session 1548 (sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89) Ended
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.651159 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1687 Close Channel sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89 [CS_DESTROY]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.651159 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:741 (sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89) Running State Change CS_DESTROY (Cur 0 Tot 1548)
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.651159 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:751 (sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89) State DESTROY
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.651159 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:343 sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89 SOFIA DESTROY
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.651159 [DEBUG] mod_opus.c:711 Opus decoder stats: Frames[0] PLC[0] FEC[0]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.651159 [DEBUG] mod_opus.c:726 Opus encoder stats: Frames[0] Bytes encoded[0] Encoded length ms[0] Average encoded bitrate bps[0]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.651159 [DEBUG] mod_opus.c:711 Opus decoder stats: Frames[0] PLC[0] FEC[0]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.651159 [DEBUG] mod_opus.c:726 Opus encoder stats: Frames[0] Bytes encoded[0] Encoded length ms[0] Average encoded bitrate bps[0]
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.651159 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:181 sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89 Standard DESTROY
3133f78a-48e9-11ea-affa-87c9172e3dc8 2020-02-06 18:01:37.651159 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:751 (sofia/internal/501@198.50.194.89) State DESTROY going to sleep
```

**UPD**. I've changed mux policy, now it also sends rtcp candidates, but error is still the same. I'm posting the other part of new log.

```
Call Details    
A detailed view of the call and all information regarding it. The information contains caller id name and number, channel data, Call variables, call flow, timing information, and other useful call details.


Summary     
Direction   Name    Number  Destination     Start   End     Duration    Status
inbound     501     501     500     2020-02-06 09:34:52     2020-02-06 09:34:52     0   INCOMPATIBLE_DESTINATION


Channel Data    
Name    Value
caps    1=1;2=1;3=1;4=1;5=1;6=1 
flags   0=1;38=1;40=1;53=1;108=1;109=1;110=1;111=1;112=1;113=1 
state   CS_REPORTING 
direction   inbound 
state_number    11 


Variables   
Name    Value
uuid    667c64fa-48a2-11ea-8dad-87c9172e3dc8 
billsec     0 
waitsec     0 
billmsec    0 
billusec    0 
duration    0 
waitmsec    0 
waitusec    0 
answersec   0 
call_uuid   667c64fa-48a2-11ea-8dad-87c9172e3dc8 
caller_id   "501" <501> 
direction   inbound 
dtmf_type   rfc2833 
end_epoch   1580967292 
end_stamp   2020-02-06 09:34:52 
mduration   0 
read_rate   48000 
sip_allow   INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, BYE, UPDATE, MESSAGE, OPTIONS, REFER, INFO, NOTIFY 
uduration   0 
answermsec  0 
answerusec  0 
end_uepoch  1580967292751178 
read_codec  opus 
session_id  1546 
sip_to_uri  500@x.x.x.x 
write_rate  48000 
presence_id     501@x.x.x.x 
progresssec     0 
sip_call_id     ktal4c8isltjt6rbodpv 
sip_full_to     <sip:500@x.x.x.x> 
sip_req_uri     500@x.x.x.x 
sip_to_host     x.x.x.x 
sip_to_user     500 
start_epoch     1580967292 
start_stamp     2020-02-06 09:34:52 
write_codec     opus 
answer_epoch    0 
bridge_epoch    0 
channel_name    sofia/internal/501@x.x.x.x 
flow_billsec    0 
hangup_cause    INCOMPATIBLE_DESTINATION 
max_forwards    69 
progressmsec    0 
progressusec    0 
sip_from_tag    db6tjls4su 
sip_from_uri    501@x.x.x.x 
sip_full_via    SIP/2.0/WS n501vr8djmj6.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK5797162;received=37.186.120.211;rport=10 90 
sip_req_host    x.x.x.x 
sip_req_user    500 
sip_via_host    n501vr8djmj6.invalid 
start_uepoch    1580967292751178 
switch_r_sdp    v=0 o=- 6699217014466542063 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1 s=- t=0 0 a=group:BUNDLE 0 a=msid-semantic: WMS 1zQJPrWkL5ow9FKSIxe6Z1OE3gjVTvPKJBMR m=audio 55562 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126 c=IN IP4 192.168.11.21 a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2 a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1 a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000 a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000 a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000 a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000 a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000 a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000 a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000 a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000 a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000 a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000 a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000 a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000 a=rtcp:55563 IN IP4 192.168.11.21 a=candidate:315564084 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.11.21 55562 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 a=candidate:315564084 2 udp 2122260222 192.168.11.21 55563 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 a=candidate:1548541124 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.11.21 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1 a=candidate:1548541124 2 tcp 1518280446 192.168.11.21 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1 a=ice-ufrag:LHl4 a=ice-pwd:S9lZWvirVjf1Z59iR8JeWEWY a=ice-options:trickle a=fingerprint:sha-256 47:FA:9A:92:B9:41:95:97:0C:37:EB:78:AE:0A:27:CE:9B:0B:B7:B0:4A:22:1B:2D:7B: 70:68:61:4E:98:3C:52 a=setup:actpass a=mid:0 a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01 a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id a=extmap:6 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id a=msid:1zQJPrWkL5ow9FKSIxe6Z1OE3gjVTvPKJBMR 3a3494d5-ee51-44ae-a94c-0f3347ebb6fe a=rtcp-mux a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc a=ssrc:3444415619 cname:mfEYD+7N9E33fNtG a=ssrc:3444415619 msid:1zQJPrWkL5ow9FKSIxe6Z1OE3gjVTvPKJBMR 3a3494d5-ee51-44ae-a94c-0f3347ebb6fe a=ssrc:3444415619 mslabel:1zQJPrWkL5ow9FKSIxe6Z1OE3gjVTvPKJBMR a=ssrc:3444415619 label:3a3494d5-ee51-44ae-a94c-0f3347ebb6fe  
answer_uepoch   0 
bridge_uepoch   0 
flow_billmsec   0 
flow_billusec   0 
hold_accum_ms   0 
sip_from_host   x.x.x.x 
sip_from_user   501 
sip_full_from   <sip:501@x.x.x.x>;tag=db6tjls4su 
sip_via_rport   1090 
progress_epoch  0 
sip_authorized  true 
sip_network_ip  37.186.120.211 
sip_user_agent  JsSIP 3.3.11 
ep_codec_string     mod_opus.opus@48000h@20i@2c,mod_spandsp.G722@8000h@20i@64000b,CORE_PCM_MODU LE.PCMU@8000h@20i@64000b,CORE_PCM_MODULE.PCMA@8000h@20i@64000b 
hold_accum_usec     0 
last_hold_epoch     0 
progress_uepoch     0 
remote_media_ip     192.168.11.21 
resurrect_epoch     0 
sip_contact_uri     55glomto@n501vr8djmj6.invalid 
sip_received_ip     37.186.120.211 
audio_media_flow    sendrecv 
last_hold_uepoch    0 
resurrect_uepoch    0 
sip_contact_host    n501vr8djmj6.invalid 
sip_contact_user    55glomto 
sip_invite_stamp    1580967292751178 
sip_nat_detected    true 
sip_network_port    1090 
sip_via_protocol    ws 
video_media_flow    sendrecv 
hangup_cause_q850   88 
progress_mediasec   0 
remote_media_port   55562 
rtp_audio_recv_pt   111 
sip_acl_authed_by   domains 
sip_received_port   1090 
hold_accum_seconds  0 
original_read_rate  48000 
progress_mediamsec  0 
progress_mediausec  0 
rtp_use_codec_fmtp  minptime=10;useinbandfec=1 
rtp_use_codec_name  opus 
rtp_use_codec_rate  48000 
sip_contact_params  transport=ws;ob 
sofia_profile_name  internal 
original_read_codec     opus 
profile_start_epoch     1580967292 
profile_start_stamp     2020-02-06 09:34:52 
rtp_use_codec_ptime     20 
endpoint_disposition    NO CODECS 
profile_start_uepoch    1580967292751178 
progress_media_epoch    0 
rtp_use_codec_string    PCMU,PCMA,OPUS,G7221@32000h,G7221@16000h,G7221@8000h,G722 
progress_media_uepoch   0 
recovery_profile_name   internal 
rtp_use_codec_channels  1 
sip_from_user_stripped  501 
sip_hangup_disposition  send_refuse 
sip_local_network_addr  x.x.x.x 
rtp_last_audio_codec_string     opus@48000h@20i@1c 


Application Log     
Name    Data


Call Flow: Attributes    
Name    Value
dialplan    XML 
unique-id   667c7170-48a2-11ea-8dae-87c9172e3dc8 
profile_index   1 


Call Flow: Extension: Attributes     
Name    Value


Call Flow: Extension: Application    
Name    Data


Call Flow: Caller Profile    
Name    Value
ani     501 
uuid    667c64fa-48a2-11ea-8dad-87c9172e3dc8 
aniii    
rdnis    
source      mod_sofia 
context     public 
dialplan    XML 
username    501 
chan_name   sofia/internal/501@x.x.x.x 
network_addr    37.186.120.211 
callee_id_name       
caller_id_name      501 
callee_id_number     
caller_id_number    501 
destination_number      500 


Call Flow: Times    
Name    Value
hangup_time     1580967292751178 
bridged_time    0 
created_time    1580967292751178 
answered_time   0 
progress_time   0 
transfer_time   0 
last_hold_time      0 
resurrect_time      0 
hold_accum_time     0 
progress_media_time     0 
profile_created_time    1580967292751178
```

**UPD 1**
I've changed muxing policy, and now it's sending rtcp candidates as well, but still doesn't working.

Comment: You may search for the error in freeswitch.log? Something may be interesting there.

Comment: @AymericM I personally find nothing there, but I'm updating my question to include freeswitch logs.

Comment: freesiwth.log is trying to find the RTCP candidate. But there is no RTCP candidate (jssip/webrtc is using muxing, so one socket only is required.). I think this is the reason for failure!

Comment: @AymericM thanks for the answer! As I am new to this field, I have to ask, from where this problem can be solved, jssip or freeswitch? I guess I should change something from freeswitch?

Comment: In your SDP from jssip, you can see line "a=candidate:315564084 1..." and line "a=candidate:1548541124 1". In javascript, you may need to make sure there is also an exact same line (but with 2 instead of 1) with ""a=candidate:315564084 2..." and "a=candidate:1548541124 2 ..." (for rtcp candidate). May be you can "fix" the SDP with javascript, or find an option to do this. I'm not a jssip programer...

Comment: May be this would help (or similar on other browser?): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCConfiguration#RTCRtcpMuxPolicy_enum

Comment: I changed rtcp mux policy from 'require' to 'negotiate',and there are 4 candidates now. It still throws the same error.But wiil it theoretically cause problems, if I keep all the 4 candidates?
`a=candidate:315564084 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.11.21 61866 typ host generation 0 network-id 1
a=candidate:315564084 2 udp 2122260222 192.168.11.21 61867 typ host generation 0 network-id 1
a=candidate:1548541124 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.11.21 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1
a=candidate:1548541124 2 tcp 1518280446 192.168.11.21 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1`

Comment: It's better to keep the change now. Anything new on the freeswitch.log?

Comment: It still is giving me the same error, I've updated my question and included the other part of log.

Comment: You haven't updated the freeswitch.log: any change here?

Comment: @AymericM oh sorry, now it's updated, check the second code block. As far as I know it's the same except two more candidates.

Comment: Then, it may be a freeswitch config issue: check this: https://lists.freeswitch.org/pipermail/freeswitch-users/2016-February/118854.html

Comment: I have noticed today that an INVITE with only "host" candidate is rejected by my freeswtich. When adding an "srflx" candidate (with STUN server), the INVITE was accepted. Thus, try adding a STUN server in your jssip config.

Answer (score 5):

The answer was posted in the comments but I found this on Google and wanted to make it more clear.

This is typically caused by a missing STUN configuration on the `ua.call()`. The JsSIP docs show an example, but for example using google STUN servers:

```
    let options = {
        'mediaConstraints': { 'audio': true, 'video': video },
        'sessionTimersExpires': 120,
        'pcConfig': {
            'iceServers': [
                {
                    'urls': ['stun:stun.l.google.com:19302','stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302']
                }
             ]
         }
    };

    this.currentSession = ua.call('sip:user@freeswitch-box.com', options)
```

Documentation from JsSIP: https://jssip.net/documentation/3.4.x/api/ua/#method_call